# Javascript to filter timestamp values to aggregated values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to take values with specific timestamps and aggregate them into 30 minute intervals.

The data looks like this,

```
0: {created: 1601820360, sentiment: -0.1, magnitude: 0.1, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
1: {created: 1601820365, sentiment: -0.8, magnitude: 0.8, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
2: {created: 1601900938, sentiment: -0.2, magnitude: 0.2, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
3: {created: 1601900956, sentiment: -0.2, magnitude: 0.2, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
4: {created: 1601900971, sentiment: 0.2, magnitude: 0.2, createdDay: "2020-10-05"}
```

The code I'm using currently looks like this,

```
function generateSentimentPoints(Sentiments) {
/** @ Create a function that parses timestamps into specific time intervals 
 * Data Constructed As: {dateCreated,sentiment,magnitude}
 * Where dateCreated is fixed to a specific time interval
 * */

 let nOfEntries = Array(24).fill(1);
 let values =  Array(24).fill(0)

  let createdDate;
  var createdDateInit;
  Sentiments.forEach((item) => {
    //for each specific date, create a new array of 24 hour intervals?
    //need to know if the date has changed at all
    if (createdDateInit != createdDate) {
      console.log("Does this conditional work, created Date Init Changing?",createdDateInit)
      var createdDay = new Date(item.created * 1000);

      var createdDate = createdDay.getFullYear()+'/'+(createdDay.getMonth()+1)+'/'+createdDay.getDate();
      nOfEntries = Array(24).fill(1);

      createdDateInit = createdDate;
    }
   

   
    const createdHour = new Date(item.created * 1000).getHours();


    values[createdHour] = values[createdHour] + item.sentiment;


    
    values[createdHour] = values[createdHour] + item.sentiment;
    nOfEntries[createdHour] += 1;

  });

  /**
   * Take average of values with the noOfEntries.
   */

  values = values.map((val, index) =>
    nOfEntries[index] - 1 === 0 ? val : val / (nOfEntries[index] - 1)

  );
```

This is getting me the first day outputting correctly, but I need it to work for everyday >< . Would love some pointers on achieving this outcome

Answer (score 1):

### `createdDate` without a time zone is ambiguous

The timestamp values held in `created` properties are in UTC, but the 5th Oct 2020 in Victoria would have been 11 hours east of Greenwich because 0ct 4th 2020 was a Sunday marking the start of daylight saving (but requiring an internet search to find out).

This impacts converting time stamps into time of day without creating a dependency on what time zone the processing device is set to.

If processing has access to the UTC offset at the place of data generation, the date in the `createdDate` property becomes largely documentary, *and* the offset expressed in seconds could simplify processing to aggregate data into 30 minute segments across multiple days in a report or table.

I would suggest that supplying the difference between the time of day of data samples and GMT, whether in data records or in meta data, is the first thing to address.